# Sum up values at corresponding indices from another list

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have 2 lists, `fantasies` and `damages`, each of length 19:

```
fantasies[0] = ("Extreme sports")
damages[0] = 250000
fantasies[1] = "Truffles"
damages[1] = 5000
....
fantasies[19] = "Coffee"
damages[19] = 50000
```

My program randomly selects `n` fantasies and prints selected values:

```
import random
i = 0
while i<n:
    print (random.choice(fantasies))
    i = i + 1
```

Now I need it to total the `damages` values, which correspond to the randomly chosen `fantasies` values.

For example, if the program randomly selects `fantasies` at indices 2, 6, and 18, I need it to sum up `damages` at the same indices. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` them into tuples and sum up the associated values:

```
import random
n = 3
data = zip(fantasies, damages)
total = 0
for i in range(n):
    myChoice = random.choice(data)
    print myChoice[0]
    total += myChoice[1]
```

There are a couple of things I should add:

1. In the future you probably would want to use dictionary to store associated values, rather than having two lists.
2. I have a feeling that you need unique choices. If so, you will need to use [shuffle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_shuffle.htm).

Comment: I'm not sure if this will cause a problem, but when the user calls the function they have to input an amount, n, to tell the program how many things to choose ------ trust_fund_monthly(n):
    """Will let you have your top n ways of spending money."""

Comment: @user3331266 Don't see why that would be a problem.